# Polling in Jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, polling

I am trying to run a test plan wherein in a thread I have multiple requests added. I need to run one event fetching requests at regular intervals of 2 seconds until the complete execution of the thread.
Can someone please help me with the same ?

I have tried running the plan by adding timers and controllers but to no use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter), it executes its children while [JMeter Function or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you set in the "Condition" input field resolves to `true`

The delay can be introduced by either using a

- [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer)  - will create a delay before each Sampler it its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
- [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) Sampler - will create a delay exactly where it's placed in the script